# Finding import static statements for Mockito constructs

Tags: java, mockito, static-import

I'm trying to crash through the brick wall between me and Mockito. I've torn my hair out over trying to get correct *import static* statements for Mockito stuff. You'd think someone would just throw up a table saying that *anyInt()* comes from *org.mockito.Matchers* and *when()* comes from *org.mockito.Mockito*, etc., but that would be too helpful to newcomers, no?

This sort of thing, especially when mixed in with myriad more import statements ending in asterisks, isn't always very helpful:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

Yes, I know about and have been trying to use the *Eclipse Window -> Preferences-> Java -> Editor-> Content Assist -> Favorites* mechanism. It helps, but it doesn't hit the nail on the head.

Any answers to this question would be appreciated.

Many thanks,
Russ

Comment: Sorry to jerk the community around: My original post also asked another question, but I discovered that it was something wrong with my code, due to a missing parenthesis, so I removed that bit.

Comment: Are you looking for a cheatsheet?  We can probably whip one up?  What's deficient about the api? http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/index.html?org/mockito/Matchers.html

Comment: So, you have to understand that I religiously avoid the asterisk in import statements because seeing that sort of thing at the top of code just means it's hopeless to know where a symbol comes from and, therefore, no way of figuring out what JAR to include in my project. Searching Javadoc in the browser isn't too good for finding symbols. Yeah, a cheat sheet would be really nice, but as a colleague and I were discussing just now, this is one of those problems you'd think the Java community would have solved by now. Thanks--let me know if you do one.

Comment: import static org.mockito.Mockito.*; helped me  successfully compiled my code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that static imports from [Hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/) and Mockito have similar names, but return Matchers and real values, respectively.

One work-around is to simply copy the Hamcrest and/or Mockito classes and delete/rename the static functions so they are easier to remember and less show up in the auto complete.  That's what I did.

Also, when using mocks, I try to avoid `assertThat` in favor other other `assertions` and `verify`, e.g.

```
assertEquals(1, 1);
verify(someMock).someMethod(eq(1));
```

instead of

```
assertThat(1, equalTo(1));
verify(someMock).someMethod(eq(1));
```

If you remove the classes from your Favorites in Eclipse, and type out the long name e.g. `org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo` and do CTRL+SHIFT+M to 'Add Import' then autocomplete will only show you Hamcrest matchers, not any Mockito matchers.  And you can do this the other way so long as you don't mix matchers.

Comment: Yup, you've nailed one of my complaints as a newbee: I'm not certain where an interface is from (JUnit, mock framework, Hamcrest, etc.) I spend more time trying to piece together a project from JARs than I really should have to (than I ever did back in day locating C interfaces from libraries and header files).

Comment: You might wax more eloquent on why you avoid assertThat: I haven't thought hard enough on it yet, but I'm just now trying to break into writing tests with mocks and the verify thing is new to me. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I have another solution for you.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 112):

Here's what I've been doing to cope with the situation.

I use global imports on a new test class.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.*;
```

When you are finished writing your test and need to commit, you just CTRL+SHIFT+O to organize the packages.  For example, you may just be left with:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doThrow;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
```

This allows you to code away without getting 'stuck' trying to find the correct package to import.

Comment: For Mac users, instead of CTRL+SHIFT+O do [command + shift + O](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/08/my-top-10-shortcuts-for-eclipse-on-mac-os-x-and-windows-and-how-you-survive-the-change-from-windows-to-mac/#comment-165299)

Comment: What is the downside to permanently using things like `import static org.junit.Assert.*;` in your test classes (not replacing them with `ctrl`+`shift`+`O` at the end)?

Comment: As I am always coming back to your reply for these 3 lines. Maybe you could update `import static org.mockito.Matchers.*;` to 
`import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.*;` 
because `Matchers` is marked as deprecated

Comment: @timguy Thanks - I'll take a look!  Hard to believe it's been 9 years...

Answer (score 5):

For is()

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
```

For assertThat()

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

For when() and verify()

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

My imports

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyInt;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.Test;
```

And it works

Answer (score 0):

import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyInt;

e.g.
when(listMock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn("stackoverflow");