# Mockito mocked object passed to child class not being used in super

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to mock authentication and pass the mocked object while instantiating the child class

```
GoogleOAuthService mockGoogleOAuthService = Mockito.mock(GoogleOAuthService.class);
mockGoogleOAuthService = Mockito.spy(mockGoogleOAuthService);
GoogleCredentials mockGoogleCredentials = Mockito.mock(GoogleCredentials.class);
mockGoogleCredentials = Mockito.spy(mockGoogleCredentials);
Mockito.when(mockGoogleOAuthService.authenticateServiceAccount(secretJson, SERVICE_ACCOUNT_SCOPES)).thenReturn(mockGoogleCredentials);
final HotelViewTpaReportService hotelViewTpaReportService =
        new HotelViewTpaReportService(mockGoogleOAuthService, dr);
```

Where the constructor of `HotelViewTpaReportService` calls `super` i.e `public HotelViewTpaReportService(GoogleOAuthService googleOAuthService, DownloadRequest downloadRequest) throws Exception { super(googleOAuthService, downloadRequest);`

And super class constructor then tries to authenticate `googleOAuthService.authenticateServiceAccount`. It should at this point return the mocked `mockGoogleCredentials` since we have written `Mockito.when(mockGoogleOAuthService.authenticateServiceAccount(secretJson, SERVICE_ACCOUNT_SCOPES)).thenReturn(mockGoogleCredentials);`. But it doesn't and tries authenticating.

```
// Super Class Constructor
public AbstractTpaReportService(GoogleOAuthService googleOAuthService, DownloadRequest downloadRequest) throws Exception {
    this.downloadRequest = downloadRequest;

    this.tpaReportConfig = new TPAReportConfig(downloadRequest);

    final byte[] secretJson = Base64.getDecoder().decode(getRequiredOption(downloadRequest, "secretJson"));

    this.googleCredentials = googleOAuthService.authenticateServiceAccount(secretJson, SERVICE_ACCOUNT_SCOPES);
}
```

I am fairly new to Java , having migrated from python and nodejs.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mockito there exist different types of mock/stub objects:

#### Mockito's mocking objects

The tutorial on Baeldung: [Mockito - Using Spies, 5. Mock vs Spy](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy#mock-vs-spy-in-mockito), differentiates the two briefly:

- **Mock**: no behavior object, mostly returning null, empty or false

  > When Mockito creates a mock – it does so from the Class of a Type, not from an actual instance. The **mock simply creates a bare-bones shell instance** of the Class, entirely instrumented to track interactions with it.
- **Spy**: object using existing behavior, mainly for verification

  > On the other hand, the **spy will wrap an existing instance**. It will still behave in the same way as the normal instance – the only difference is that it will also be instrumented to track all the interactions with it.

#### Use only Mock

There are a few things, you should do different & simpler:

- You have already created `Mock` objects. Don't overwrite them with `Spy` objects.
- Use `any()`, better typed [`ArgumentMatchers.any(Your.class)`](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any(java.lang.Class)) or similar as *argument-matcher* when defining the mocked return

```java
// Arrange
  GoogleOAuthService mockAuthService = Mockito.mock(GoogleOAuthService.class);
  // mockGoogleOAuthService = Mockito.spy(mockGoogleOAuthService);

  GoogleCredentials mockCredentials = Mockito.mock(GoogleCredentials.class);
  // mockGoogleCredentials = Mockito.spy(mockGoogleCredentials);

  // defining a mocked response, using `any()` as argument-matcher
  Mockito.when(mockService.authenticateServiceAccount(any(), any()).thenReturn(mockCredentials);

  // injecting the mock
  final HotelViewTpaReportService hotelViewTpaReportService =
 new HotelViewTpaReportService(mockAuthService, dr);

// Act
```

#### Advanced Mockito usage

Since using mocks should simplify your test code, there are even more elegant or ideomatic ways using Mockito (in JUnit-) tests - compare it to "pythonic":

- use **annotations** (`@Mock`, `@Spy`, `@InjectMocks`) to declare & instantiate plus inject mocks
- use **`static import`s** to shorten usage of Mockito's helper-methods in most readable way

Your code could look like:

```java
// import some useful static methods
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doThrow;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;

class MyTest {

  // first creating the mocks
  @Mock
  final GoogleOAuthService mockAuthService;
  @Mock
  final GoogleCredentials mockCredentials
  
  // then injecting the mocks
  @InjectMocks
  final HotelViewTpaReportService hotelViewTpaReportService;

  @BeforeEach
  public void beforeEach() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    // could also define mock-behavior here, using `when(mockedObject. ..)`
  }

  @Test
  public void testAuthentication() {
    // Arrange
    // defining a mocked response specific for your test
    when(mockService.authenticateServiceAccount(any(), any()).thenReturn(mockCredentials);

    // Act
    // ... your code here

    // Assert
    // ... your code here
  }
```

#### See also:

- [Creating Mocks and Spies in Mockito with Code Examples](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/mocks-spy-mockito/)
- [java - ArgumentMatchers.any() versus the other matchers in Mockito 2 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287635/argumentmatchers-any-versus-the-other-matchers-in-mockito-2)
- [java - Finding import static statements for Mockito constructs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322705/finding-import-static-statements-for-mockito-constructs)